# Salesforce transaction mutexes

Tags: apex, transaction, concurrency

This is more of a theory question.

We have a use case where an object field is the sum of the records existing in the system + 1.

This method is going to be accessed via force remoting. My worry is that 2 users could access this resource at the same time and then two objects will be inserted with the same number.

How does salesforce handle transaction orders on methods, and is it possible for two users to have obtain the resource at the same time and generate the same number?

```
webservice static createObject() {
    Object obj = new Object();
    Object.field_increment__c = [Select Id FROM Object].size() + 1;
    insert object;
}
```

^ is it possible for two users to access this and insert two objects with the same number?

edit:

I suppose it would be possible to use a metadata object if this is a problem and lock the record on a query to the resource and update the value for the next user.

```
webservice static createObject() {
    Object obj = new Object();
    Custom_mdt__c nextValue = [SELECT Value FROM Custom_mdt__c FOR UPDATE];
    nextValue.Value = String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(nextValue.Value) + 1));
    update nextValue;

    obj.field_increment__c = nextValue.Value;
    insert obj;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how your proposed `mdt` solution can work as `mdt` objects can't be used with `For Update`

Comment: @cropredy I don't have access to the org I wrote this for, but it is possible we used a custom object or custom setting instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, two transactions can absolutely overlap. Let's say for instance that `Object` takes about two seconds to save. Until that transaction completes, the number of records in the database won't change. So if you get five hits per second over a certain time span, the first ten will have the same value.

A couple of notes:

- There is a field type of `Auto-Number` that takes care of this issue for you (though it is not writeable)
- It is much more efficient to perform a count query:

  ```
  Integer recordCount = [SELECT count() FROM MyObject__c];
  ```

---

In regards to your updated solution, yes, implementing row locking should work (in theory). I would be cautious in using this approach, however, because it may drastically increase your risk of timeouts.

Comment: Thanks, our use case is a little more complex than the example but the idea is the same. I edited my question and provided a solution that I think would work as well. Basically grab the next value from a metadata object and set a lock on it that will prevent the next user from accessing it.

Comment: Off hand, if we use the record lock soql is it possible to queue the waiting users? Or will they need to keep pressing save until they have access? I'm worried about starving users from the resource

Comment: It would simply extend the length of the transaction. See [Locking Statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm) for more detail. You could possibly move that field update to a `@future` method to increase reliability and reduce the impact on transaction time. As long as you don't need to return the value...